# C# replaced data table cell values are not retained

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a Datatable and replace the cell values with given code but when I return the table the cell values which are replaced are not taken into account and original table is returned. How to retain the replaced cell values?

```
    public static DataTable GetDataTable(IList<string> headerList, IList<IList<string>> rows)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        foreach (string header in headerList)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(header);
        }
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
            foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    string celltext = r[i].ToString();
                    if (celltext == "-")
                    {
                        celltext.Replace("-", "");
                    }
                }


            }
        }


        return table;
    }
```

Comment: You have to assign the replaced string back to the cell... `r[i] = celltext.Replace("-", "");`

Comment: Thanks! solved my problem